# An issue with storing Collections in struts http session attribute

Tags: jsp, collections, struts2, arrays, httpsession

I am facing a strange issue while storing session attributes 
I am storing a JSONArray in session as a string

```
JSONArray serverDetails = jsonResponse
                        .getJSONArray("details"); //server returns details in json format   
ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession().setAttribute("serverDetails", serverDetails.toString());
```

Say while loading index.jsp , the following data is stored in session

```
[{"id":"10","si":"1000","ti":"300"},{"id":"40","si":"2000","ti":"400"}]
```

Then in jsp when I hit next button , I again fetch next set of details from server , and in struts action I will again set the JSONArray to session attribute as shown in the above code.

now the data will be different , and in struts action before setting it in session the details looks like below

```
 [{"id":"100","si":"500","ti":"600"},{"id":"1040","si":"250","ti":"70"}]
```

In ajax success block, I will try to get the same details using getAttribute in jsp , but strangely getAttribute returns the old value not the updated while ( note new will is setting properly in action method )

just for the curiosity I tried to set some string other than jsonarray , then I didn't see any issue , so I confirmed that there is nothing wrong while setting or getting the values.

Then I tried to store ArrayList values instead of JSONArray , again the same issue.

How it behave strange for JSONArray and other collection objects ?

Another thing is , it worked for me in many other cases, only in the above given case it is not working.

Comment: It's really odd, did you try Struts session map?

Comment: @RomanC even map is not working as expected :(

Answer (score 0):

first Object Set Correctly.

```
"serverDetails" :[{"id":"10","si":"1000","ti":"300"},{"id":"40","si":"2000","ti":"400"}]
```

Next when you call Ajax Function.That data is belong to `ResponseData` it means you can able get data via `ResponseData.serverDetails` only.not achieve through getAttribute. even-though you tried.it Obviously return `Old Data`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/haridharan/Pth92/1/)  Check This Link.....

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "Strutsaction",
      dataType: "JSON",
     success:function(ResponseData){
                  $.each(ResponseData.serverDetails,function(i,v){
                         alert(i+""+v);
                   });
                 }
         });
```

Comment: the object is correct, and I knew that in ajax response we can do. but in ajax response it will add extra quotes some times , I have to remove them. So trying to get it from session